# Create a reporting template using Excel, then populate specific data points from another worksheet, output in .pdf

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, mongoose-populate

On a quarterly basis I need to produce multiple reports (~400) from an Excel file. I use Excel because I need it calculate specific details for the reporting period. The calculations are then fed into a template used to create ~400 reports. The only difference between each report is the product name and contract start/stop date, I copy/paste each product into the template to create .pdf report for distribution. On a separate tab in the workbook each product is tracked. I use to copy/paste into the template and as a checklist to make sure I've created all the reports. As you can imagine it is very labor intensive to create each individual report. Since I maintain the product details on a different tab in the workbook I'm trying to see if there is a way to create an output each reports that just populates the product name and start/stop dates saves each .pdf file using the product name.

Comment: It's certainly possible (reading Excel, generating PDFs), but you'll likely need someone to code this with/for you.

Comment: Thank you Adam, I agree.  I tried looking for some examples of folks that have similar questions with code I could apply to my question but I couldn't find.

Comment: So I'm not sure what SO guidelines/procedure is for such a situation, but I've done this type of automations before (read, transform, generate), and have a friend getting started with coding. I'd be willing to work with you and him to put something together, so he can gain some coding experience and mention the project on his CV - WDYT?